# How to Setup NServiceBus 3.2.2 Distributor

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NSB3.2.2 and facing a problem in setting up distributors.
I have one publisher and two load balanced workers.

The workflow is like this:

- Publisher sends message to Service1 distributor
- Service 1 distributor send it to Service1 worker
- Service1 worker  send a message to Service2 distributor
- Service2 distributor sends it to Service2 worker
- Service2 worker  does bus.Reply( response message)

Now the question is where should Service2 worker reply go?

I observe that sometimes it’s going to Service1 distributor input queue and sometimes going to Service1 worker  input queue

I want Service2 worker Bus.Reply() to send message to Service1 worker input queue. What should be the configuration to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the following sample, it demonstrates one way to configure the Distributors the way you want:

https://github.com/shlomii/NServiceBus-Scale-Out-Sample-set-up-for-Publish-Send-Reply-environment

Answer (score 1):

Replies go back to the distributor in all cases - that's how it's supposed to work. If you are concerned about which server replies go back to, you might have some in-memory state that should be distributed as well, like with a distributed cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Reply message is coming in distributor InQueue but distributor is not forwarding that message to call initiating Worker

Comment: That's right - the distributor picks one of the workers at random, not necessarily the worker that sent the original request.